# How to update a div in a View, by class, from another View?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

In my main view, I have an empty placeholder div that I fill with an inner view on a user click. I want to be able to have several copies of the same inner view in my main view, with different data tied to each inner view.

The main view has its own model and controller, and the inner view has its own model and controller. When an item is selected in the main view, the inner view fills with data pertaining to the selection. I get this data from a web service based on the id of the item that was selected, so I can't fill the inner view's model with data, until that point.

Since the multiple view divs can't all have the same ID, I can't use something like `@Ajax.ActionLink` with `UpdateTargetId`. Instead, I declared it `<div class='placeholderDiv' title='@[some_unique_id]'>`, and I can draw the multiple divs successfully using the following in my main view:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'id': id },
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
    success: function (result) {
        $(".placeholderDiv[title=" + id + "]").html(result);
    }
});
```

Now, I want the user to be able to update the model in the inner view. I am able to do this in the inner view's controller, but I can't get the changes to display. How am I supposed to access the div with the class `placeholderDiv` in the main view, from the inner view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for "outsourcing" your "inner view" to client-side templates. That way, you can have a standard template defined somewhere (maybe in your main view?), and all you do is fetch your model from your services, bind it to a copy of your template/s, and then render that onto the page.

A great templating library I'm looking at right now is [DustJS](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/). Using it, I can define a template like so (note that this has to be defined only once in your page):

```
<div id="{id}">
    <h1>{name}</h1>
    {?accounts}
    <ul>
        {#accounts}
        <li>Account Number : {accountNumber}</li>
        {/accounts}
    </ul>
    {:else}
    <p class="error">No accounts for this user.</p>
    {/accounts}
</div>
```

... then bind a model such as the following (which can be returned by your service):

```
{ 
    id : '123456',
    name : 'TheBeatlemaniac',
    accounts : [
        { accountNumber : 'FOO1234' },
        { accountNumber : 'BAR1234' },
        { accountNumber : 'FOB1234' }
    ]
}
```

... and that will automatically render markup like so:

```
<div id="123456">
    <h1>TheBeatlemaniac</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Account Number : FOO1234</li>
        <li>Account Number : BAR1234</li>
        <li>Account Number : FOB1234</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

... and finally, you can slap that onto your main view container as you so please.

There are definitely other ways to do what you want to do, but I'm recommending this on the rationale that it's (generally) lighter on your bandwidth, because all you have to return back is (for example) JSON data corresponding to your model. If you request data from the service, and it returns fixed HTML markup with just key changes, the redundancy quickly adds up. You let the server-side code release some of its supposedly necessary processing, so that may be a good thing.